# Return a string between two characters '.'

Tags: r, regex, substr, names

I have column names similar to the following

```
names(df_woe)

# [1] "A_FLAG" "woe.ABCD.binned" "woe.EFGHIJ.binned"       
 ...
```

I would like to rename the columns by removing the "woe." and ".binned" sections, so that the following will be returned

```
names(df_woe)
# [1] "A_FLAG" "ABCD" "EFGHIJ"       
 ...
```

I have tried `substr(names(df_woe), start, stop)` but I am unsure how to set variable start/stop arguments.

Comment: could names have the `woe` part but not the `binned` (or vice versa)?

Comment: No, they all have "woe." and ".binned", except for the A_FLAG column

Comment: @Sotos post as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
nam <- c("A_FLAG", "woe.ABCD.binned", "woe.EFGH.binned")
gsub("woe\\.|\\.binned", "", nam)
[1] "A_FLAG" "ABCD"   "EFGH"
```

EDIT: a solution that deals with wierder cases such as `woe..binned.binned`

```
gsub("^woe\\.|\\.binned$", "", nam)
```

Comment: What if its `woe.binned.binned`?

Comment: @PoGibas good question, maybe snoram has the answer, but that would not apply to my dataset.

Comment: @PoGibas Than this would return `binned` with `woe..binned.binned` it returns `` which I guess can be dealt with separately (in the unlikely case) `names(df_woe)[names(df_woe) == ""] <- "so_woe_binned"`

Comment: How would you modify this if the names did not include the first part, i.e. "ABCD.binned" ?

Comment: Nevermind, I have figured it out myself   
gsub("|\\.binned", "", names(df_woe))

Comment: You don't need to change anything... for that case.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible and readable regex can be to create groups and return the group after the first and before the second dot, i.e.

```
gsub("(.*\\.)(.*)\\..+", "\\2", names(df_woe))
#[1] "A_FLAG" "ABCD"   "EFGH"
```

Comment: Why not simplify to: `gsub(".+\\.(.*)\\..+", "\\1", names(df_woe))`?

Comment: @snoram that too. Maybe 100 more too ;)

Comment: How would you modify this if the names did not include the first part, i.e. "ABCD.binned" ?

Comment: @NatalieKing that is why I asked you in the comments of your question but you said that woe and binned will always exist together. Obviously If one of the two is missing we need to use a different approach

Comment: @Sotos in my data, woe and binned will always exist. I was just curious

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, using `stringr` package:

```
 str_replace_all("woe.ABCD.binned", pattern = "woe.|.binned", replacement = "")
 # [1] "ABCD"
```

Comment: This also works perfectly, thank you! I also prefer this method as it looks cleaner (in my opinion)

Comment: @zx8754 it works for the purpose which I think is everything we can ask for.

Comment: How would you modify this if the names did not include the first part, i.e. "ABCD.binned" ?